# echo $(date +%s -d "+1 day 6:30") using sudo crontab -e

Tags: linux, bash, cron

**Main-agenda:** I am trying to automate shutdown and restart of my computer using `cron`. To be exact, I want to shutdown my computer at 10:30 pm and restart my computer at 06:00 am everyday.

**Progress so far:**

1. I can automate shutdown. (I don't even use `cron`. I just use `sleep $duration; poweroff`. And `duration` is computed as target time minus current time).
2. For automating restart I am following [this askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/83706/154488). I could successfully run the "Simple test to wake the machine 5 minutes from now". It works fine!
3. Now comes the part where I try to figure out: how to use `cron`. So I basically want to run something like this everyday:

   `sudo sh -c "echo $(date +%s -d '+1 day 6:30') > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm"`

   (Remark: standalone, the above works fine).
4. So I try this: `sudo crontab -e` and added the following line there:

   `*/1 * * * * echo "$(date +%s -d '+1 day 6:30')" > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm`

   Remark: I am using `*/1 * * * *` for testing purposes only. Finally when everything works I plan to use `@reboot`.
5. The above doesn't work. So I have tried looking online and debugging. From [this unix.stackexchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52332/267021) I get the idea that "by default `cron` is using `sh` to run the task instead of `bash`". So I added `SHELL=/bin/bash` in the `sudo crontab -e` file.
6. Next I have broken the above `echo` into simpler things and now, I know some of them work and some of them don't.

Currently, the output of `sudo crontab -l` is:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
*/1 * * * * echo "$(date)" > /home/username/a.txt
*/1 * * * * echo "1659800001" > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm
*/1 * * * * echo "$(date +%s)" > /home/username/b.txt
*/1 * * * * echo "$(date +%s -d '+1 day 6:30')" > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm
```

Of these - the first 2 commands execute correctly! However the 3rd and 4th commands don't execute. 4th command is what I want to work.

So my guess is that `$(date +%s)` is the problem? Please help me proceed from here!

Comment: If you're trying to send the time in seconds, why the `$`? Why not just `date +%s -d '+1 day 6:30' > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm`? I sense I'm missing something

Comment: Thanks! The answer below also alluded to this. So I have responded to this in a comment to the answer. I still have a few questions. Please feel free to respond in that comment. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition about the % is correct. See `man 5 crontab`:

> A "%" character in the command, unless escaped with a backslash (), will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the first % will be sent to the command as standard input.

This will work with the % escaped:

```
*/1 * * * * echo "$(date +\%s -d '+1 day 6:30')" > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm
```

However, I wonder why you want to do the echo? This will also work:

```
*/1 * * * * date +\%s -d '+1 day 6:30' > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm
```

Comment: Yes that works. The reason I was trying `echo` was: because `sudo date +\%s -d '+1 day 6:30' > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm` would give: `bash: /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm: Permission denied`. However `sudo sh -c "echo $(date +%s -d '+1 day 6:30') > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm"` was working. I also tried with `sh` but I got: `sh: 1: cannot create /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm: Permission denied`. I wrongly concluded from this that `echo` must be necessary somehow. Just if you know: can you tell why the above wouldn't work in a `bash` prompt or in `sh` prompt?